# Magento 2 : Custom module - Shipping per product

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have created custom shipping method named ad **My Shipping Method** and have created custom attribute named **my_Shipping_charge**. Both are working fine without any error.
Now I want to set condition if **my_Shipping_charge** has any value then it will consider it as shipping charge otherwise default charges of My Shipping Method should be apply.

For example, 
default charges set in My Shipping Method is 10 
my_Shipping_charge for product A is null 
my_Shipping_charge for product B is 15 
my_Shipping_charge for product C is 5 
 
Then total shipping charge should be 10+15+5

```
    private function getShippingPrice()
    {
        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);

        /*To find cart details */
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');        

        /*To find number of items available in cart */ 
        $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $itemNum = count($itemsVisible);

        /*To find quantity of item */
        $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        $finalShippingChargeOfProduct = 0;

        foreach($items as $item) {

            $qty = $item->getQty();
            $product_id = $item->getProductId();
            $customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id); 
            $myShippingAtt = $customProduct->getData('my_shipping_charge');
            settype($myShippingAtt, "integer");

            if($myShippingAtt <= 0)
            {
                $finalShippingChargeOfProduct += $shippingPrice*$qty;
            }    
            else 
            {
                $finalShippingChargeOfProduct += $customProduct->getData('my_shipping_charge')*$qty;
            }            
        } 
        return $finalShippingChargeOfProduct; 
    }
```

Everything is working fine but error in loop. custom attribute value is not correct everytime.

Comment: is this working for admin new orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$customProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

to

```
$customProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

**Suggestion:** use product repository instead of using object manager and deprecated **load** method

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!! @sohel  It's working perfectly.